# Firebase events are not recording from subset of devices

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We are using firebase to log events for later doing analytics. But there is some issue with the numbers. Number of devices which recorded at least one event is ~20% less than the total number of devices. which is happening in all the platforms. Anyone facing this issue ?

Note: we are recording events right after user signup in the app. so these number should be almost same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Events could arrive late and aggregate eventually so there could be the reason why you see the discrepancy. How did you base the difference on? Is that the same date/week?

Comment: But at least it will be aggregated in a day or in a week right ? But i was checking devices added days back. @adbitx

Answer (score 0):

You said that the events are recorded after users sign up in the app. However, users may download, open the app for a few seconds and close the app without signing up. In the mean time, some automatic events may have been sent. Therefore, the number of events may look fewer than the number of devices.

Comment: But i don't think it will end up with 20% users having 0 events. And in android even if user deleted application play service will take care of delivering recorded events to the firebase server.

Comment: Public events may not show up in some users, but note that they may have other automatic events that make them qualify as users, like engagement events, which the report doesn't display.